# They are crazy for doing that?

Tags: verb-forms

I want to say that **they are crazy** because they did **that/something** or they do **that/something**. Is this form correct:

They are crazy for doing that.

Comment: In a bit different situation, it may sound more natural. `I would call them crazy for making a suit out of aluminum foil and carrying around seven crosses, holy water, three versions of the Bible`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have worded it is acceptable:

> Those guys skateboarded in San Francisco? They are crazy for doing that!
>   Oliver asked for more soup? He's crazy for doing that!

However, in some contexts, we can make this more concise (and this would often be considered an improvement):

> Those guys skateboarded in San Francisco? That's crazy!
>   Oliver asked for more soup? That's crazy!

In cases like these, if you say that the acts are crazy, that implies the people are crazy for doing them.

I would guess most natives wouldn't pick up on any difference in meaning between the two wordings.